# Run Rscripts from python script in Windows

Tags: python, r, windows, rscript

I am creating a GUI in python that should run on UNIX and windows. From the main script in python I need to execute RScripts, in the case of operative system Unix I don't have problems with it I use this:

```
import subprocess 
...
if "Linux" in o_sys or "Darwin" in o_sys:
    subprocess.call(["/usr/bin/Rscript", "--vanilla", "General_plots.r"])
    subprocess.call(["/usr/bin/Rscript", "--vanilla", "Heatmaps.r"])
```

But in the case of Windows I have no idea of how execute the Rscripts.
Do you have some advice?

Comment: `subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "script"])`?

Comment: How could I execute my, for example, Heatmaps.r script with this code? It should be some like this?: subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "Heatmaps.r"]) Windows will call R to execute it?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of info in my comment, you need to replace sys.executable with path to R executable, I think you can even use subprocess.call like that.

Comment: Simply find where Rscript.exe resides and replace that path in `subprocess.call`. Even better if Rscript is an environment variable in all OS's, no need for absolute path!

Comment: Thank you for your answers! Do you know where Rscript.exe could be in a general Windows OS? The idea of this is make a program that could be run in all computers not only in mine. Or do you know how to set Rscript as an enviroment variable in Windows?